# Problem with bold and italic arial font in title and sections?

Tags: bold, italic

I'm writing my maturity paper with LaTeX and I have the two following problems:

1. One word in the title needs to be italic. I've tried `\textit{}` but it won't work.
2. As soon as I changed the font to `arial` the boldness of the sections and contents was gone.

I have the following parts:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arial}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=4cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Maturaarbeit 2019}

\cfoot{Seite \thepage}

\title{Spielt die Proteinkinase Snf1 beim erhöhten P-Body Aufbau eines $\Delta$\textit{arc18} 
Hefestamms eine Rolle?}
```

Do you know how I can solve the two mentioned problems?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Would you please post  a *complete* small code reproducing the problem?

Comment: You look like you are using pdfLaTeX, right? How do you get the Arial font? Have you tried the 'winfonts' package? I use it a lot. There is however an issue with Arial Bold-Oblique coming out as Arial Bold. This is solvable by fixing the .vf file and rebuilding the .tfm. (I've done it.)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want the entire document in Arial, and are able to compile with xelatex/lualatex, `fontspec` package command `\setmainfont` can be used, and `\textit` works OK anyway no problems:

[image: arc18]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{arial}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=4cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Maturaarbeit 2019}

\cfoot{Seite \thepage}

\title{Spielt die Proteinkinase Snf1 beim erhöhten P-Body Aufbau eines $\Delta$\textit{arc18} 
Hefestamms eine Rolle?}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

xxx
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Cicada that you should use OpenType fonts in LuaLaTeX if you can, and legacy fonts in PDFTeX when you have to.  (This would need another few lines of code to set up math mode.)

The `arial.sty` file that your template uses is not a standard package.  You would need to give us more information to tell what’s wrong.  My guess is that it tries to use Arial through `winfonts`, but you don’t have the files installed.

If you are required to use PDFTeX, there is [a download intended to let you use a number of Windows fonts.](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/winfonts)  You would want to stick it in your local TeX tree (`kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFLOCAL` in TeX Live, or add one in MikTeX), then run `texhash` and `updmap-sys`.  Unfortunately, it doesn’t work with recent versions of the font, but a very old version from the ’90s is still *gratis* to download as part of the Microsoft Core Fonts for the Web.  With the version this package expects, the following code might work:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=4cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\renewcommand\sfdefault{arial}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Maturaarbeit 2019}

\cfoot{Seite \thepage}

\title{Spielt die Proteinkinase Snf1 beim erhöhten P-Body Aufbau eines $\Delta$\textit{arc18} 
Hefestamms eine Rolle?}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

If you’re allowed to, you can change to a different clone of Helvetica.  TeX Gyre Heros ships with TeX Live and MikTeX.  URW Arial [is also available *gratis*,](https://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/) under a restrictive license.  You could combine them with a sans-serif math font with `\usepackage{mathastext}`.

If any sans-serif font would work for you, Fira Math and KpMaht-Sans have OpenType math support.  Legacy sans-serif math fonts include Arev Sans, Computer Modern Bright and `newtxsf`.